# Render utf8 characters in pdf

Tags: xetex, pdftex, unicode

I have a *.tex document encoded in UTF-8 which includes these characters:

```
⎡6  1⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣5  3⎦
```

I'm having troubles reproducing such characters (apart from the numbers of course). I tried the following combinations all failing for different reasons. I'm on MacOS 10.6, if that matters:

- Compile with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` with or without `\usepackage{fontspec}`: The pdf output displays the matrix above as "6 1  5 3" (all in one line, and only numbers and blanks).
- Use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` and compile with `pdflatex` results in the error:

`Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 9121 = U+23A1`,

Any idea how to render the matrix above? Also, these are not the only "unusual" characters I might come across later so I'd like a general solution if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to typeset that as math, without the need of crafting glyphs?

Comment: @Johannes_B You mean in equation env as `\left[\begin{matrix}6 & 1\\5 & 3\end{matrix}\right]`? Sure, but I'm copying this output from a terminal window (from python SymPy to be precise) and I'd like to be able to paste it in the tex document as is.

Comment: How are you handling linebreaks?

Comment: The tex file has \n (newline, line feed) as EOL character, I'm writing it in Komodo Edit.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `pmboxdraw` together with `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw,newunicodechar,fancyvrb,graphicx}

\newunicodechar{⎡}{\raisebox{1ex}{\makebox[.5em]{\textSFi}}}
\newunicodechar{⎤}{\raisebox{1ex}{\makebox[.5em]{\textSFiii}}}
\newunicodechar{│}{\makebox[.5em]{\textSFxi}}
\newunicodechar{⎣}{\raisebox{-1ex}{\makebox[.5em]{\textSFii}}}
\newunicodechar{⎦}{\raisebox{-1ex}{\makebox[.5em]{\textSFiv}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
⎡6 1⎤
│   │
⎣5 3⎦
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I understand it each character has to be "registered" with \newunicodechar. The example I showed has just some of unicode chars I came across so I was hoping for a simpler and more general solution like `\usepackage{enable-all-UTF8-chars}`.

Comment: @dariober That's simply hopeless.